# virtualenv hangs before writing to bin

Tags: python, virtualenv

Virtualenv consistently hangs right after successfully installs pip, setuptools, and wheel. Executing `virtualenv venv -v` in my home directory, or in any other directory on the VM, outputs:

```
Creating /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib/python2.7
Symlinking Python bootstrap modules
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib/python2.7/config
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/os.py
  Ignoring built-in bootstrap module: posix
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py
  Cannot import bootstrap module: nt
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/ntpath.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/genericpath.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/fnmatch.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/locale.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/encodings
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/codecs.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/stat.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/copy_reg.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/types.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/re.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/sre.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/sre_parse.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/sre_constants.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/sre_compile.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/warnings.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/linecache.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/_abcoll.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/abc.py
  Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
Creating /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Writing /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/site.py
Writing /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/orig-prefix.txt
Writing /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/no-global-site-packages.txt
Creating parent directories for /home/stephen.kasica/venv/include
Symlinking /home/stephen.kasica/venv/include/python2.7
Creating /home/stephen.kasica/venv/bin
New python executable in /home/stephen.kasica/venv/bin/python
Changed mode of /home/stephen.kasica/venv/bin/python to 0755
Testing executable with /home/stephen.kasica/venv/bin/python -c "import        sys;out=sys.stdout;getattr(out, "buffer", out).write(sys.prefix.encode("utf-8"))"
Got sys.prefix result: u'/home/stephen.kasica/venv'
Creating /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/distutils
Writing /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py
Writing /home/stephen.kasica/venv/lib64/python2.7/distutils/distutils.cfg
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-25.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pip
Collecting wheel
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip, wheel
Successfully installed pip-8.1.2 setuptools-25.2.0 wheel-0.29.0
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

It hangs here, and never outputs the following lines.

```
Writing venv/bin/activate
Writing venv/bin/activate.fish
Writing venv/bin/activate_this.py
Writing venv/bin/activate.csh
```

When I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> out, it spits out this Traceback, but I'm not sure if it's related to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or this issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 711, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 944, in   create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 900, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 767, in call_subprocess
    line = stdout.readline()
  KeyboardInterrupt
```

I'm running virtualenv version 15.0.3, I upgraded from 15.0.1 after reading [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682263/creating-a-new-virtualenv-hangs). Python is version 2.7.5. The whole thing is running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.2 (Maipo)

Comment: I'm having the exactly same issue on Fedora 24

Comment: @david8, I found a way around this, but it was so long ago I can't remember exactly what I did. I'm pretty sure I just cleared pip's cache and it worked again. I wish I could remember more, good luck.

Comment: amazing, clearing the cache solved the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like clearing pip's cache solves this problem. I really wish someone knew why though.